# Use SharePoint database backups and restore on new site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, sql-server

I suspect my client's SharePoint site is 'corrupt'.  Some links give "File not found" for example when going to a certain sub site's settings.  They have SharePoint 2016 with SQL 2014 on Windows 2012 R2.

I want to backup the broken SharePoint's databases and restore them on a 'clean' SharePoint installation (also SP 2016 with SQL 2014).

I've read up on methods and saw there are different methods.  Which one will be best in this scenario - and which databases do I backup?  Is there a link maybe with step by step instructions to backup all SP databases and restore them on another installation of SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start to backup and restore the databases... are you using the correct URL to access the Site? Do you have Events with the ID of 8059 in the Windows Event logs > Applications log folder?

You can check the configured Alternate Access Mapping using the **Central Administration** > **System Settings** > **Configure alternate access mappings**

Usually this happens when you use the Web Application with the wrong URL.

Comment: Thank you David, I'll investigate on this as well.  If this will fix the problem, I'll be a very happy lady.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps which we followed all the times.

- make sure both farm should be on same patch level.
- if you have any custom solution in current then it should be deploy to new environment
- backup of the content database from the current farm ( make sure you get the copy of backup when site was working fine). You cant use current database as site is already corrupted in it.
- Now restore the database on new farm's sql server
- attach the content database to web app in new farm
- Now browse the site and test if you get good copy of site's backup.

Comment: Should I only backup the content database?  What about the search and other databases?

Comment: What you want to do? just restore the site in new farm and bring it back to old farm or site will permanently moved to new farm.

Comment: I want to restore the site in a new farm, see if the errors is gone.  If it fix the error pages, then I want to re-install SP on the current site and restore the database there.  Or are there another way to 'fix' the current site if I suspect that is has problems?